# I used the find command without specifying a directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, find, chmod

I used this command without specifying a directory:

```
sudo find -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \
```

What could have happened? I was in the /var/www/html folder. Did it change any permissions outside the /var/www/html directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a `;` or a `{} +` and can skip path (to run **find** starting in current dir)

```
sudo find -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

In this case your search start in current directory with subdirs. But You can set directory obviously.

Current dir:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Absolute path:

```
sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

### Explanation:

`sudo` - run as superuser

`find -type d` - search **directories only** (if you need files only use `find -type f`. If You isn't matter files or dirs, just remove **-type d[f]** from command).

`-exec chmod 755 {} \;` - run command **chmod 755** for each founded object in command which init -exec param (in this case **find** command).

`-exec chmod 755 {} +` - run command **chmod 755** for full array of founded results at once..

Comment: Your missing the point OP used a command and left out the `directory` part but like you observed OP also didn't  add `;` after `\\` so the command didn't run or did it? That is what OP is trying to find out if any damage was done!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen yep, thanks! I started answering a more complex question in this context, but then noticed a typo and fix..

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu uses GNU `find`,  which assumes current working directory if you don't specify one. Specifically, it assumes `.` and all items that are found by the command will have `./` prefix to their path when passed to `-exec` command. So it would only traverse `/var/www/html`;  if your current working directory really was in `/var/www/html` nothing outside of that would be affected.  Other implementations of `find` may require directory argument as BSD `find` for example.

However, as [mature's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099340/295286) mentioned, your syntax is incomplete, hence that command wouldn't run. The `\` at the end would tell the shell the command is incomplete and show `PS2` prompt which is `>`